# define USE(x) (x) = (x)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In one of the C source code files I found the following line (macro):

```
#define USE(x) (x) = (x)
```

It is used like this:

```
int method(Obj *context)
    {
    USE(context);
    return 1;
    }
```

After googling for it, I found the following description:

> // Macro to get rid of some compiler
>   warnings

Could you please tell me more about this macro?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @DrTJ: Are you user507960? Anyway, it can't be `x = USE(10);` because the expanded macro `x = (10) = (10);` won't compile.

Comment: Macro is defined in .h file, but one of the examples looks like this: int method(Obj *context)
{
    USE(context);
    return 1;
}

Comment: @user: Edit this into your question. Anyway, looks like TokenMacGuy has answered your question already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some compilers complain when variables are never actually used for anything.  for instance:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
Output from llvm C/C++/Fortran front-end (llvm-gcc)

/tmp/webcompile/_7618_1.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/webcompile/_7618_1.c:9: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
/tmp/webcompile/_7618_1.c:9: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
```

Queerly, I can just get rid of those warnings using your macro:

```
#define USE(x) (x) = (x)


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  USE(argc); /* get rid of warnings */
  USE(argv); /* get rid of warnings */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The compilers give warnings when a variable is defined/declared but never used. These include function arguments. Some coding styles require to always name function arguments, but some of them may not be used in the function. They are reserved for future use. For these cases you could `USE(param)` to avoid the warning

Comment: @the_drow in some case you will be required to compile your code with "Treat Warnings As Errors" compiler option.

Comment: @the_drow: It's usually a bad idea to keep any warnings. When you get used to them, you finally won't read them anymore and then miss the important ones. It's an even worse idea to try to simply silence them by some workaround, e.g. a cast, instead of eliminating its reason. Of course, sometimes the solution actually *is* a cast. Another common version of the USE macro is `#define USE(x) ((void)(x))`.

Answer (score 5):

With gcc you can use `__attribute__((unused))` to suppress the warning.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't portable.

Answer (score 4):

Most (if not all) major compilers will offer warnings if local variables are not used within the function they are defined.  I imagine that macro does an arbitrary operation on some variable to ensure that no warning is flagged for the variable.

```
void func1(void)
{
    int unusedVariable = 0;
    /* do stuff without using unusedVariable */
} /* warning about not using unusedVariable */

void func2(void)
{
    int unusedVariable = 0;
    USE(unusedVariable);
    /* do stuff without using unusedVariable */
} /* no warning is issued */
```